# join two inline tables - unknown column?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I'm getting "Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'E1.extensao' in 'field list'". I changed table names but my query is as follows:

```
SELECT E1.stateName, E1.city, E1.boughtEnough, E2.bought
FROM 
    (SELECT count(DISTINCT idClient),city,stateName FROM
        (SELECT
            max(n.ordervalue) as boughtEnough,
            m.idClient,
            i.nome AS city,
            i.id AS cityId,
            i.stateName
        FROM Clients c
        INNER JOIN client_order m ON c.idClient = m.idClient
        INNER JOIN orders n ON m.client_order = n.client_order
        INNER JOIN orderDetail p ON n.idorder = p.idorder
                                AND p.idCurso = m.idCurso
        INNER JOIN cities i ON c.city = i.id

        WHERE
            m.idCurso = '10'
        GROUP BY 
            m.idClient,
            i.nome,
            i.id,
            i.stateName
        HAVING max(n.orders) >= 6) t
    GROUP BY t.city, t.stateName
    ORDER BY t.stateName,t.city) E1
JOIN (SELECT count(DISTINCT idClient),city,stateName FROM
        (SELECT
            count(n.ordervalue) as bought,
            m.idClient,
            i.nome AS city,
            i.id AS cityId,
            i.stateName
        FROM Clients c
        INNER JOIN client_order m ON c.idClient = m.idClient
        INNER JOIN orders n ON m.client_order = n.client_order
        INNER JOIN orderDetail p ON n.idorder = p.idorder
                                AND p.idCurso = m.idCurso
        INNER JOIN cities i ON c.city = i.id

        WHERE
            m.idCurso = '10'
        GROUP BY 
            m.idClient,
            i.nome,
            i.id,
            i.stateName
        HAVING ((max(n.orders) < 6) AND (count(n.orders) >= 1))) t
    GROUP BY t.city, t.stateName
    ORDER BY t.stateName,t.city) E2 ON E1.cityId = E2.cityId
```

I'm more used to SQL Server, not MySQL. What am I getting wrong?

Comment: `E1.extensao` doesn't seem to appear anywhere in your query. Are you sure that the error message is coming from this query?

Comment: I may be missing something, but I'm not sure the `t` is supposed to be on the HAVING lines.

Comment: @TomvanderWoerdt - it's an alias for the subselect I think

Comment: Ah, yes, must've missed that. Thanks for pointing it out @JNK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that `E1.extensao` means `E1.boughtEnough`? Look closely at how `E1` is defined:

```
    (SELECT count(DISTINCT idClient),city,stateName FROM
        (SELECT
            max(n.ordervalue) as boughtEnough,
        ...) t
    ...) E1
```

There's a `t.boughtEnough`, but you're not "passing it up" to `E1`.

Comment: If that's true, this post should be merged to the community wiki as an example why you shouldn't ever translate your code before posting it here.

Comment: @TomvanderWoerdt: I half-agree. Yes, it's risky if you mess it up, but if you get it right, it can make the query much clearer to English-speakers. (Portuguese-language identifiers are almost the exact opposite of self-documenting code, at least for those of us who don't speak Portuguese!) The problem, of course, is that it's easy to mess it up, for example (in this case) by not translating the error-message to match; but the OP mitigated that by stating outright that (s)he had changed the identifiers.